# null is not an object (evaluating 'I.setJSAnimations')

Tags: javascript, android, gradle, react-native

I'm developing a react-native app that use React-viro for augmented reality. My app works fine in develop mode, but when I try to build it on my phone by android studio or 'react-native run-android', it say that the build is succesful but when the app open on my phone it show the error: "null is not an object (evaluating I.setJSAnimations"), and when i build the APK the app crash instantly.
I don't know how to individuate the problem, any help?

my build.gradle file:

```
import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
       compileSdkVersion 28
   buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    flavorDimensions "platform"

signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
    compileSdkVersion 28
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
 multiDexEnabled true
        applicationId "com.namedSportAR"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
        productFlavors {
        ar {
            resValue 'string', 'app_name', 'ViroSample-ar'
            buildConfigField 'String', 'VR_PLATFORM', '"GVR"' //default to GVR
        }
        gvr {
            resValue 'string', 'app_name', 'ViroSample-gvr'
            buildConfigField 'String', 'VR_PLATFORM', '"GVR"'
        }
        ovr {
            resValue 'string', 'app_name', 'ViroSample-ovr'
            applicationIdSuffix '.ovr'
            buildConfigField 'String', 'VR_PLATFORM', '"OVR_MOBILE"'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':@react-native-firebase_app')
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
    // implementation project(':arcore_client')
    // implementation project(':gvr_common')
    // implementation project(path: ':viro_renderer')
    // implementation project(path: ':react_viro')
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.7.1'
   // implementation 'com.google.protobuf.nano:protobuf-javanano:2.7.1'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.7.7'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:2.7.7'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb-mapper:2.7.7'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.7.7'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognitoidentityprovider:2.7.7'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
```

my app.js file:

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2017-present, Viro, Inc.
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the BSD-style license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree. An additional grant
 * of patent rights can be found in the PATENTS file in the same directory.
 */

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  PixelRatio,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Image,
  Icon
} from 'react-native';

import {
  ViroVRSceneNavigator,
  ViroARSceneNavigator
} from 'react-viro';


var sharedProps = {
  apiKey:"2803D6A6-AAFE-4CAB-823F-E7433072671D",
}

// Sets the default scene you want for AR and VR
var InitialARScene = require('./src/PlayScene');


var UNSET = "UNSET";
var VR_NAVIGATOR_TYPE = "VR";
var AR_NAVIGATOR_TYPE = "AR";

// This determines which type of experience to launch in, or UNSET, if the user should
// be presented with a choice of AR or VR. By default, we offer the user a choice.
var defaultNavigatorType = UNSET;

export default class ViroSample extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      navigatorType : defaultNavigatorType,
      sharedProps : sharedProps
    }
    this._getExperienceSelector = this._getExperienceSelector.bind(this);
    this._getARNavigator = this._getARNavigator.bind(this);
    this._getVRNavigator = this._getVRNavigator.bind(this);
    this._getExperienceButtonOnPress = this._getExperienceButtonOnPress.bind(this);
    this._exitViro = this._exitViro.bind(this);
  }

  // Replace this function with the contents of _getVRNavigator() or _getARNavigator()
  // if you are building a specific type of experience.
  render() {
    if (this.state.navigatorType == UNSET) {
      return this._getExperienceSelector();
    } else if (this.state.navigatorType == VR_NAVIGATOR_TYPE) {
      return this._getVRNavigator();
    } else if (this.state.navigatorType == AR_NAVIGATOR_TYPE) {
      return this._getARNavigator();
    }
  }

  // Presents the user with a choice of an AR or VR experience
  _getExperienceSelector() {
    return (
      <View style={localStyles.outer} >


        <View style={localStyles.inner} >
        <Image
                  style={{marginTop: 50, marginBottom: 50, width: 200, height: 50}}
          source={require('./assets/logo.png')}
          />    
 <TouchableHighlight style={localStyles.buttons}
            onSubmit={this._getExperienceButtonOnPress(AR_NAVIGATOR_TYPE)}
            underlayColor={'#68a0ff'} >

            <Text style={localStyles.buttonText}>realtà aumentata</Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>


        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }

  // Returns the ViroARSceneNavigator which will start the AR experience
  _getARNavigator() {
    return (
      <ViroARSceneNavigator {...this.state.sharedProps}
        initialScene={{scene: InitialARScene}} />
    );
  }

  // Returns the ViroSceneNavigator which will start the VR experience
  _getVRNavigator() {
    return (
      <ViroVRSceneNavigator {...this.state.sharedProps}
        initialScene={{scene: InitialVRScene}} onExitViro={this._exitViro}/>
    );
  }

  // This function returns an anonymous/lambda function to be used
  // by the experience selector buttons
  _getExperienceButtonOnPress(navigatorType) {
    return () => {
      this.setState({
        navigatorType : navigatorType
      })
    }
  }

  // This function "exits" Viro by setting the navigatorType to UNSET.
  _exitViro() {
    this.setState({
      navigatorType : UNSET
    })
  }
}

var localStyles = StyleSheet.create({
  viroContainer :{
    flex : 1,
    backgroundColor: "#EF7D1A",
  },
  outer : {
    flex : 1,

    alignItems:'center',
    backgroundColor: "#EF7D1A",
  },
  inner: {
    flex : 1,

    alignItems:'center',
    backgroundColor: "#EF7D1A",
  },
  titleText: {
    paddingTop: 30,
    paddingBottom: 20,
    color:'black',
    textAlign:'center',
    fontSize : 25
  },
  buttonText: {
    color:'black',
    textAlign:'center',
    fontSize : 20
  },
  buttons : {
    height: 80,
    width: 150,
    paddingTop:20,
    paddingBottom:20,
    marginTop:250, 
    justifyContent: 'center',

    alignItems:'center',
    backgroundColor:'#EF7D1A',
    borderRadius: 10,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#000000',
  },
  exitButton : {
    height: 50,
    width: 100,
    paddingTop:10,
    paddingBottom:10,
    marginTop: 10,
    marginBottom: 10,
    backgroundColor:'#68a0cf',
    borderRadius: 10,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#fff',
  }
});

module.exports = ViroSample
```

my PlayScene.js file:

```
'use strict';

import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {StyleSheet,Linking} from 'react-native';

import {
  ViroBox,
  ViroARScene,
  ViroText,
  ViroConstants,
  Viro3DObject,
  ViroAmbientLight,
  ViroMaterials,
  ViroARTrackingTargets,
  ViroARImageMarker,
  ViroAnimations

} from 'react-viro';

export default class HelloWorldSceneAR extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();

    // Set initial state here
    this.state = {
      text : "Initializing AR..."
    };

    // bind 'this' to functions
    this._onInitialized = this._onInitialized.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ViroARScene  onTrackingUpdated={this._trackingUpdated}>

      <ViroAmbientLight color="#FFFFFF" />
      <ViroARImageMarker target={'logo'} onAnchorFound={this._onAnchorFound}    onAnchorRemoved={this._onAnchorRemoved} pauseUpdates={this.state.pauseUpdates}>

      <Viro3DObject onLoadEnd={this._onModelLoad}
      onClick={this.loadInBrowser}
        source={require('./assets/ns/AMINONAM-obj.obj')}
        resources={[
                   require('./assets/ns/AMINONAM.mtl'),
                   require('./assets/ns/TEX_OK.jpg'),
                   require('./assets/ns/WHITE.jpg'),
                   require('./assets/ns/arancio.jpg'),
          ]}
       highAccuracyEvents={true}
        position={[0, 0.02, 0]} // we place the object in front of us (z = -1)
        scale={[0.001, 0.001, 0.001]} // we reduce the size of our Marmelab logo object
        animation={
          {name:'popup', 
          run:true},
          {name:'ruota',
        loop:true, 
        run:true}
                            }
        rotation={[0, 0, 0]}
        type="OBJ"

    />
      </ViroARImageMarker>
      </ViroARScene>
    );
  }
  loadInBrowser = () => {
    Linking.openURL('https://www.namedsport.com/it/').catch(err => console.error("Couldn't load page", err));
  };  

  _onInitialized(state, reason) {
    if (state == ViroConstants.TRACKING_NORMAL) {
      this.setState({
        text : "NamedSport!"
      });
    } else if (state == ViroConstants.TRACKING_NONE) {
      // Handle loss of tracking
    }
  }
}

ViroAnimations.registerAnimations({

  ruota:{properties:{rotateY:360,},  
        easing:"Linear", duration: 10000},
});


 ViroARTrackingTargets.createTargets({
       logo: {
           type: 'Image',
           source: require('./assets/namedsport-box.jpg'), // source of the target image
           orientation: 'Up', // desired orientation of the image
           physicalWidth: 0.07, // with of the target in meters (10 centimeters in our case)
       },
   });

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  helloWorldTextStyle: {
    fontFamily: 'Arial',
    fontSize: 30,
    color: '#ffffff',
    textAlignVertical: 'center',
    textAlign: 'center',  
  },
});

module.exports = HelloWorldSceneAR;
```

Comment: Please refer https://github.com/viromedia/viro/issues/324#issuecomment-402835783

Comment: i'm using android studio and don't have the setup-ide --all command in my project directory but only in my \node_modules\react-viro\bin directory... I tried to copy and paste de sh file in my project directory and when I run the command it appears a second command line interface for less then 1 second and then it disappear